# Registering dependent async service locators in get_it Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection

I have two services to register. One is `LocationService` and another is `HomeViewModel`. `HomeViewModel` depends on initialization of `LocationService`. But right now I am getting this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: Bad state: This instance of the type LocationService is not available in GetIt If you have registered it as LazySingleton, are you sure you have used it at least once?
```

Here's how I am registering them:

```
setupLocators(){
getIt.registerSingletonAsync<LocationService>(() async {
    final locationService = LocationService();
    await locationService.init();
    return locationService;
  }, signalsReady: true);
getIt.registerSingletonAsync<HomeViewModel>(()async => HomeViewModel(),
      dependsOn: [LocationService]);
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind. Here is the solution for those who are looking.

```
setupLocators(){
locator.registerSingletonAsync<LocationService>(() async {
    final locationService = LocationService();
    await locationService.init();
    return locationService;
  });
locator.registerSingletonWithDependencies<HomeViewModel>(() {
    return HomeViewModel();
  }, dependsOn: [LocationService]);
 }
```

Now, the HomeViewModel only gets registered when LocationService is registered which is after completing the async initialization.

Comment: thanks i tried to register in one line like LocationService()..init() but seems not work